# SQL - How to count number occurrences in specific column while also selecting other colums

Tags: sql

I am trying to work out how to count the number of female and male employees from the total number of employees and put them in separate columns next to the total number of employees. Here is my code:

```
select cd.dept_no, d.dept_name, count(cd.dept_no) as 'No. Current 
Employees', e.gender from current_dept_emp as cd
inner join departments as d on cd.dept_no = d.dept_no
inner join employees as e on e.emp_no = cd.emp_no
where cd.to_date = '9999-01-01'
group by cd.dept_no, e.gender
order by cd.dept_no
```

It is returning the following result

[image: screen]

How do I get my desired output?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select cd.dept_no, d.dept_name,
       count(*) as num_current,
       sum(case when e.gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as num_males,
       sum(case when e.gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as num_females
from current_dept_emp cd inner join
     departments d
     on cd.dept_no = d.dept_no inner join
     employees e
     on e.emp_no = cd.emp_no
where cd.to_date = '9999-01-01'
group by cd.dept_no
order by cd.dept_no;
```